# Angular custom directive use scope variable in filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a little trouble with my angular custom directive. I want to access the "type"-variable in my filter, which is filterung objects (on the first level, so it should be possible without a custom filter).

This is the (very basic so far) structure:

```
angular.module('....').directive('ngTest', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  scope: {
    list: '=',
    type: '@'
  },
  template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="information in list | filter:{ttype:type}">....</li></ul></div>'
  }
});
```

Is there a way to access the variable in the template-string? Neither escaping nor using a template html file worked for me..

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your filter from the scope variables using the link function.

It's slightly less awkward, and it will give you more flexibility to alter the filter in the future.

```
angular.module('....').directive('ngTest', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      list: '=',
      type: '@'
    },
    template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="information in list | filter:filterOb">....</li></ul></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.filterOb = { ttype: scope.type }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HkWFxQkMigxhtx9EfO0?p=preview) where instead you pass the whole filter object to the directive, instead of just a string - that way you can filter on anything you want without altering the directive

Answer (score 0):

After renaming the variables and rewriting the directive it suddenly works:

```
    <li ng-repeat="information in list | filter:{ttype:type}">{{information.value}}</li>
```

Sometimes its just.. awkward. 
Nevertheless: Thanks!